# Flutter expanded vertical line

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `ListView` and I need an expanded vertical line on the left of it (*See image below*). I have achieved the following layout but it expands to infinite.

[image: Line expanding to infinite]

Here is the code for the above layout:

```
return Scaffold(
  ...
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: 4.0,
            child: SizedBox.expand(),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: StreamBuilder( // Creates the list view
              stream: ...,
              builder: ...,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
};
```

Line goes to infinite because of `SizedBox.expand()` but how to fit into the screen. Any suggestions?

Or is there a way to get this same effect from `ListView` item (*Doesn't have a fixed size*).

Comment: Why not directly wrap your `Column` with that border instead of using a Row ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Then I have to use another Row to wrap the Column and the container with the line. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Column as Parent if you only has one child, this is working for me:

```
  return Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 4.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                // Creates the list view
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    title: Text(list[index].toString()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: how to get dynamic width insead of `width: 4.0`?